# Yii export to excel

Tags: php, yii, phpexcel

extension https://github.com/hscstudio/yiiheart

how do I export my data from sql query \ array? with the proviso that there is no data in the model. current state of affairs:

```
public function actionExport()
{
    $model = new Element;
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if (isset($_POST['Element']))
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Element'];
    $exportType = $_POST['fileType'];
    $this->widget('ext.heart.export.EHeartExport', array(
        'title' => 'List of Element',
        'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
        'filter' => $model,
        'grid_mode' => 'export',
        'exportType' => $exportType,
        'columns' => array(
            'id',
            'name',
            'type_id',
            'f_filter',
            'comment',
            'measure',
            'name_pk',
            'name_value',
        ),
    ));
}
```

---

on

```
public function actionExport()
{
    $model = new Element;
    $model->unsetAttributes();  // clear any default values
    if (isset($_POST['Element']))
        $model->attributes = $_POST['Element'];
    $exportType = $_POST['fileType'];
    $this->widget('ext.heart.export.EHeartExport', array(
        'title' => 'List of Element',
        'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
        'filter' => $model,
        'grid_mode' => 'export',
        'exportType' => $exportType,
        'columns' => array(
            'id',
            'name',
            'type_id',
            'f_filter',
            'comment',
            'measure',
            'name_pk',
            ['value'=>15,'id' => [[19, 3], [24, 34]]],
        ),
    ));
}
```

> Error 500 call_user_func_array() expects parameter 1 to be a valid
>   callback, no array or string given